# Error 252 : b"2.1.5 Send some mail, I'll try my best f18sm1267047wiv.14"

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

Hi I've written a Python script to send a simple message. The script works with my university email address. However, with gmail there seems to be a problem. I've tried using both my email and just login as a login name - same result. The error I get is:

```
Error 252 : b"2.1.5 Send some mail, I'll try my best f18sm1267047wiv.14"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I really couldn't find much info. All I get is the above line, nothing else. I'm running the script on a Linux machine and it was written on a linux machine.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.1

def sendmail(recepient,  msg):

    import smtplib

    # Parameters
    sender = 'login@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'
    smtpStr = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtpPort = 587
    # /Parameters

    smtp_serv = smtplib.SMTP(smtpStr, smtpPort)
    smtp_serv.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    smtp_serv.starttls()
    smtp_serv.ehlo()

    recepientExists = smtp_serv.verify(recepient)
    if recepientExists[0] == 250:
        smtp_serv.login(sender, password)
        try:
            smtp_serv.sendmail(sender, recepient, msg)
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            print(recepientExists[1])
    else:
        print('Error',   recepientExists[0], ':',  recepientExists[1])

    smtp_serv.quit()

sendmail('receiver@gmail.com',  'hi')
```

Comment: Neatest error message I've seen

Comment: Yes, 252 is the Cannot VRFY (verify) the user – the server will accept the message and attempt to deliver it.

Comment: Googling for it seems to point that google needs some kind of authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Nobody supports VRFY because it's such an aid to spam. Pull out that check and it should work OK.

Comment: OK so what I had is send only if VRFY works. Now I've updated the condition to send if error code is below 400 which should be OK.

Comment: But VRFY doesn't give an answer any more. It'll always return the "Send some mail, I'll try my best" message - whether it's a valid address or not. When people allowed it, you could spam easily because you knew in advance what addresses were valid. In other words, using VRFY at all is a waste of time

Comment: Hmm I thought so. I'll remove it!